# Returning a dynamically created array from function

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm trying to create a function that would dynamically allocate an array, sets the values of the elements, and returns the size of the array. The array variable is a pointer that is declared outside the function and passed as a parameter. Here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>  
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  

int doArray(int *arr) {  
    int sz = 10;  
    arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * sz);  

    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {  
        arr[i] = i * 5;  
    }  

    return sz;  
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  

    int *arr = NULL;  
    int size = doArray(arr);  

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {  
        cout << arr[i] << endl;  
    }  

    return 0;  

}
```

For some reason, the program terminates on the first iteration of the for loop in main()! Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing in the array pointer *by value*; this means that when your `doArray` function returns, the value in `arr` in `main` is still `NULL` - the assignment inside `doArray` doesn't change it.

If you want to change the *value* of `arr` (which is an `int *`), you need to pass in either a pointer or a reference to it; hence, your function signature will contain either `(int *&arr)` or `(int **arr)`. If you pass it in as a `**` you'll also have to change the syntax inside the function from using `arr` to `*arr` (pointer-dereferencing), and you'll call it like so: `doArray(&arr)`.

Also, in C++ you should really be using `new int[sz]` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allocate memory that way you have to use:

```
int doArray(int*& arr)
```

else the pointer will only be changed inside the function scope.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an extra level of indirection to `doArray`. As written it allocates the array properly but it doesn't communicate the pointer value back to the caller correctly. The pointer from `malloc` is lost once you return.

If you wrote a function to take a float and change the value, passing the changed value back to the caller, it would need to take a pointer: `foo(float *f)`. Similarly, here you want to pass back an `int*` value to the caller so your function must be declared as `doArray(int **arr)` with a second asterisk.

```
int doArray(int **arr) {  
    int sz = 10;  
    *arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * sz);  

    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {  
        (*arr)[i] = i * 5;  
    }  

    return sz;  
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  

    int *arr = NULL;  
    int size = doArray(&arr);  

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {  
        cout << arr[i] << endl;  
    }  

    return 0;  

}
```

Notice how it now dereferences `*arr` inside of `doArray`, and how the call is now written as `doArray(&arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `arr` variable in your function is a local *copy* of the `arr` pointer in the main function, and the original is not updated. You need to pass a pointer-to-pointer or pointer reference (the former will also work in plain c, the later only in c++).

```
int doArray(int **arr)
```

or

```
int doArray(int*& arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change signature to (specific for c++):

```
int doArray(int *&arr)
```

so pointer would be changed at exit from doArray.

Answer (score 0):

You need a pointer to a pointer in your doArray() parameter. If you've never done any programming with pointers before, this can be confusing. I find that it can be easier to see the right types if you annotate your code abundantly with typedefs.

You have the right idea that (int*) can be used to represent an array. But if you want to change the value of your variable arr in main(), you need a pointer to *that*, and so you will end up with (untested code) something like the following

```
typedef int *IntArray;

int doArray(IntArray *arr) {  
    int sz = 10;  
    *arr = (IntArray) malloc(sizeof(int) * sz);  
    IntArray theArray = *arr;

    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {  
        theArray[i] = i * 5;  
    }  

    return sz;  
}
```

when calling doArray, you will need to pass the address of your variable (so doArray knows where to write to):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  

    int *arr = NULL;  
    int size = doArray(&arr);  

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {  
        cout << arr[i] << endl;  
    }  

    return 0;  

}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you're passing your array (the int *) by value, so when you say `arr=...` you're not actually changing the array you passed in.

You're also got a memory leak, as you've written it.  It's not a big deal when you only call `doArray` once in the body of your program, but if it gets called repeatedly and the array is never `free`d (or `delete`d, if you made it with `new`) then it can cause problems.  Typically the best way to deal with this is by using the [STL](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/class-libraries.html).  You'd then write

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int doArray(std::vector<int> &arr) {  
    int sz = 10;
    arr.resize(sz);  
    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {  
        arr[i] = i * 5;  
    }
    return sz;  
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
    std::vector<int> arr;
    int size = doArray(arr);  
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {  
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;  
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

However, with the STL there are more idomatic ways than returning the size, since you can just ask for `arr.size()`, and if you get really fancy, can use functions like `for_each` or the `ostream_iterator` to print all your elements.